# Where can I get more information on wordpress comments.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I'm having some issues with my comments.php template file. I can't find any solution on the codex provided by wordpress, plus I've searched trough dozens of forums with no answers... my actual problem is that my comments wont appear when I click on the comments link inside the post.

What exactly triggers them for each post and how can I find out what's wrong?

Comment: You can get a quicker response by posting it at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can even use the comments.php file that comes with default wordpress template. I suspect there is something wrong you are doing. Make sure that you have coded/converted it correctly. Look through various wordpress template tutorials to get and idea on how to do it the right way :)